# Numerical coincidence with constants

Tags: physical-constants

Is there a reason why

$$\dfrac{h}{ec}\sim 1.38\cdot 10^{-23} V/(m\cdot s^{-2})$$

?

Dimensionally, the Unruh effect temperature reads

$$T_U=\dfrac{\hbar a}{2\pi k_B c}$$

from which the acceleration prefactor is

$$\left[\dfrac{ET}{E/t\times LT^{-1}}\right]=t\times \dfrac{a}{LT^{-2}}$$
Is an accident the above quantity mimic the value of almost the Boltzmann constant?

Take now the equation:

$$T=qa$$

and $$q=\dfrac{h}{k_Bc}$$

Dimensionally

$$\dfrac{ET}{(E/t)\times L/T}=\dfrac{t}{LT^{-2}}
$$

Comment: Which values mimic? You've got one number and one dimensional analysis.

Comment: Notice that the units in the denominator of your first line look like miliseconds (if we ignore that fact that you have set them in italics)? Use a thing space or a dot to set them apart: `m \, s` gets $m \, s$ or `m \cdot s` gets $m \cdot s$ And while you're fixing that set them in an unright font (I like to use `\mathrm` for that): $\mathrm{m \cdot s}$.

Comment: Does the dimensional analysis of the Unruh effect have something to do with the numerical coincidence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's a coincidence. The units on the two expressions don't match, which means the "numerical agreement" between the two numbers is definitely artificial.

Boltzmann's constant is given in SI units by

$$k_B = 1.3806 \times 10^{-23} \frac{\text{J}}{\text{K}}.$$

The ratio $h / ec$ is given in SI units by

$$\frac{h}{ec} = 1.3795 \times 10^{-23} \frac{\text{kg}\, \text{m}}{\text{C}}.$$

The second expression has a unit of charge in it, while the first does not. We are free to rescale our definition of a "Coulomb" by any number we like, and would obtain a drastically different numerical value for $h / ec$ in our chosen units without changing the numerical value of $k_B.$ In general, if two quantities don't have the same units, then there is no meaningful way of comparing their numerical values, since those values are highly dependent on the choice of units.

Answer (score -5):

This is indeed a numerical coincidence in the SI system.

This is because the SI system does not have the capacity to show this to be a valid expression.
In another system of units such as the Metre-second (MS) system, this expression can be shown to be a valid expression.

Let us consider the SI units and the equivalent MS units in square brackets:

Metre,  m = [m^1 s^0]       length

Second, s = [m^0 s^1]       time

Kilogram, kg = [m^1 s^-6]   mass

Coulomb, C = [m^5 s^-2]     electric charge

Kelvin, K = [m^6 s^-4]      temperature

Joule, J = [m^3 s^-8]       energy

The Boltzmann constant expression in MS units is shown below.  The MS units shown in square brackets are resolved by adding and/or subtracting the exponents as per normal exponent “product” and “quotient” rules for each of the two units of measurement.

kB = h/(e x c) = 1.38e-23 J[m^3s^-8]/K[m^6s^-4]

where,

kB = 1.37951e-23 J/K    [m^-3s^-4]      Boltzmann’s Constant

h = 6.62607e-34 Js [m^3s^-7]           Planck’s Constant

e = 1.60218e-19 C [m^5s^-2]             elementary charge

c = 2.99792e+8 m/s [m^1s^-1]            speed of light in a vacuum

The interpretation of physics is limited by the SI system due to the loss of a number of "hidden expressions" such as this one.

Comment: I have never heard of this system of units. I am highly skeptical about this entire post.

Comment: It is wise to be skeptical about this system of units.  It is also unfortunate that you never heard of it.  It is a new and novel system of units which uses an algorithm to derive the units.  It reveals a hidden problem with the SI system of units which is the source of the interpretation issues in QM.  This system will never appear in any journal, so the intent of the post is to raise concerns about the SI system of units.